# How to create GAR files for apache ignite

Tags: ignite

I am new to ant scripts. Could anyone share any sample ant scripts for creating GAR files for apache ignite.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the structure of a GAR file here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/deployment-spi#section-gar-file

It's up to you how to build a GAR file. You can use Ant, Maven, Gradle, etc. or just ZIP it manually.

Also note that JAR files are also supported by deployment SPI. So if you don't have nested dependencies and don't want to specify the list of task to deploy in a descriptor, there is no need to create GARs.